# Rails render ignoring content_type hash value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have an action on one of my resources to download an attachment file.  The code is pretty simple

```
  def download
    content_type = @book.attachments[params[:name]]['content_type']
    data = @book.read_attachment(params[:name])
    render :text => data, :content_type => content_type
  end
```

However rails is completely ignoring this and setting the response to text/html every time no matter what.  I've even tried setting it using response.header['Content-Type'] to no effect.

I'm using rails 3.1 if it matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using send_data instead.

```
send_data data, :type => content_type
```

Comment: That causes it to be directly downloaded (instead of opened in a browser page) but the type is still text/html

Comment: Ok so I think it's working, something with Chrome and "not modified" is causing it to show the old content type.  Changing the content query address seems to help.